# Is it a good idea to do Masters in multiple subjects rather than doing a PhD?

Tags: phd, research-process, masters

Suppose, someone already has a Masters in CS/EE. Say, he wants to work with Robotics.

Is it a good idea to do a 2nd/3rd Masters-by-research in Robotics rather than doing a PhD in CS/EE (concentration Robotics)?

Why or why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on your goals, so doesn't have a definite answer. For industrial work, another masters might work, as would some actual work experience. In fact, for some jobs a doctorate might be viewed as a negative: "We want do-ers here, not just think-era".

But if you want a successful career in academia, then you really need to get a doctorate. You would be very limited there without it. Hard to get a job, hard to advance.

Examine your goals and then find a path to achieve them. In fact, many paths might be followed to the same goal.

Comment: hmm..... good advice.